# Jquery table tr:odd

Tags: jquery, tablerow

I have this js code:

`$(".main-vervolg .right .bottom .panes table.grey tbody tr:odd").css("background-color", "#f8f8f8");`

And it is working fine but when I have 2 separated tables with the class grey he is counting further in the second table but I want that he will starts again.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$('.main-vervolg .right .bottom .panes table.grey').each(function() {
  $('tbody tr:odd', this).css("background-color", "#f8f8f8");
});
```

It loops through all tables with selector